# TYPO3 condition page check localization

Tags: php, mysql, typo3

I want to check, if there is a localization of the current page:

```
[page["localized"] == 1]
  do something
[end]
```

or do it with a custom condition something like `SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page["uid"] IN (l10_parent)`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/UseSiteInConditions.html

```
[siteLanguage("locale") == "de_CH.UTF-8"]
    page.40.value = bar
[global]
```

You can check if the locale is not the default or there may be other siteLanguage attributes which you can use.

Comment: THX. it is a litte bit more complicated, i have to explain.
I want to use it in backend. So if there is no translation of a given page in backend, i want to disable functions for be-users like the menu:
    mod.web_layout.menu.functions {
        2 = 0
    }